# Formulating a constraint on the SUM of the magnitudes of a set of vectors in a constrained optimization

Tags: geometry, optimization, vectors, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm solving a geometric constrained optimization problem. The variables in the optimization are the $x-y$ components for a set of vectors (given by $v_i.x,v_i.y$ for vector $i$). The objective function is quadratic in these variables.

However, I need to constrain the SUM of the magnitudes of a subset of the vectors.

Specifically, suppose this subset consists of $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$

I need the solution to satisfy

$$\|v_1\|_2 + \|v_2\|_2 + \dots + \|v_n\|_2 < L$$

If it was just a single vector $v$ I could square both sides to get a quadratic constraint and frame the problem as a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program

$$\|v\|_2^2=(v.x)^2 + (v.y)^2 < L^2$$

However, I have multiple vectors. So is there any way to express the constraint in such a way that I could apply a technique more specific than general non-linear constrained optimization? Could I formulate it as a second order cone program?

Or given that my objective function can be minimized analytically, would it make sense to solve the problem by

1. Ignoring the constraint and obtaining an optimum value $x^*$ for the objective function
2. Projecting $x^*$ onto the constraint manifold numerically to get a final solution that satisfies the constraints?

Comment: I'm confused, your constraint is $\sum_i vx_i^2 + vy_i^2 \le L$? That is a quadratic constraint. Did you mean $\sum_i \| (vx_i,vy_i)\| \le L$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes that's what I meant. Fixed now.

Comment: It's a second-order program, as you already pointed out, so unless you have reasons not mentioned, it can/should easily be solved as an SOCP

Comment: @JohanLöfberg his constraint involves sum of radicals ($\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}<L$).

Comment: Precisely, an SOCP model is thus $||v_1||\leq t, ||v_2||\leq s, s + t \leq L$

Comment: Yep, Thanks Johan!

Comment: @JohanLöfberg dynamic programming?

Comment: This is basically as simple an SOCP can be so I don't see why one try to attack it as using DP

Comment: @JohanLöfberg is there closed form? I do not know much about SOCP.

Comment: No, but it is a convex optimization problem so it is easy to model and solve using standard software